# problem in using while loop in a calculator project

Tags: python, math, calculator

I am creating a calculator and in that I have used a while loop, so that the user can do the calculations again and again. But there is some problem in the while loop.

This is the code:

```
print("CALCULATOR")

def addint(n1,n2):

    sum = n1 + n2

    return sum

def minusint(n1,n2):

    minus = n1 - n2

    return minus

def mult(n1,n2):

    multsum = n1 * n2

    return multsum

def div(n1,n2):

    divsum = n1 / n2

    return divsum

n1 = int(input("Enter First Number:\n"))

n2 = int(input("Enter Second Number:\n"))

n3 = str(input("Which Operator?\n"))

while n1 <= 0:

    if n3 == '+':

        print(f"The answer is {addint(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '-':

        print(f"The answer is {minusint(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '*':

        print(f"The answer is {mult(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '/':

        print(f"The answer is {div(n1,n2)}")

    else:

        print("INVALID OPERATOR")

    break
```

and this is the output window:

```
CALCULATOR

Enter First Number:

20

Enter Second Number:

10

Which Operator?

-
```

The problem occurring is that when I use the while loop after that in the output window the calculations are not happening as they are expected to happen. The output window just closes after I enter the numbers and the operator. The second problem is that the user cannot do calculations again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. While loop runs the code inside as long as the condition is true. In this case, the condition is n1 <= 0. Therefore, if n1 = 20 the loop will not run even once. If you want an infinite loop, use **while True**.
2. There is a **break** keyword at the end, so the loop will only run once.
3. Your program will print the same result forever because the input instructions are outside of the loop.

Working example:

```
def addint(n1, n2):
    sum = n1 + n2
    return sum

def minusint(n1, n2):
    minus = n1 - n2
    return minus

def mult(n1, n2):
    multsum = n1 * n2
    return multsum

def div(n1, n2):
    divsum = n1 / n2
    return divsum

while True:
    n1 = int(input("Enter First Number:\n"))
    n2 = int(input("Enter Second Number:\n"))
    n3 = input("Which Operator?\n")

    if n3 == '+':
        print(f"The answer is {addint(n1,n2)}")
    elif n3 == '-':
        print(f"The answer is {minusint(n1,n2)}")
    elif n3 == '*':
        print(f"The answer is {mult(n1,n2)}")
    elif n3 == '/':
        print(f"The answer is {div(n1,n2)}")
    else:
        print("INVALID OPERATOR")
```

Notice that converting **input("Which Operator?\n")** to str is unnecesarry, because input function returns string.

Answer (score 0):

Why the while condition is "while n1 <= 0" ?
Right off the box, you entered n1 = 20 which is NOT <=0. So, it doesn't enter the while loop at all.

Comment: ok i tried it but it still didnt work

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
while True:
    n1 = int(input("Enter First Number:\n"))
    n2 = int(input("Enter Second Number:\n"))
    n3 = str(input("Which Operator?\n"))

    if n3 == '+':
        print(f"The answer is {addint(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '-':
        print(f"The answer is {minusint(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '*':
        print(f"The answer is {mult(n1,n2)}")

    elif n3 == '/':
        print(f"The answer is {div(n1,n2)}")

    else:
        print("INVALID OPERATOR")
```

Comment: yes its working but now only the calculations are happening I cant do the calculations again and again

Comment: Can you describe the problem better? Maybe you still have the "break"

Comment: thanks sir but my problem is solved now but appreciate the time you spent on my code